# Py.Test : Reporting and HTML output

Tags: python, reporting, pytest

This is not a technical question at all really. However, I can not locate my .HTML report that is supposed to be generated using:

> py.test --cov-report html pytest/01_smoke.py

I thought for sure it would place it in the parent location, or the test script location. Does neither and I have not been able to locate. So I am thinking it is not being generated at all?

Comment: Have you tried `py.test --help`?

Comment: Yes, I had. I'll post here to show it gives no more info than I have already.     `--cov-report=type   type of report to generate: term, term-missing,
                        annotate, html, xml (multi-allowed)`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think you also need to specify the directory/file you want coverage for like `py.test --cov=MYPKG --cov-report=html` after which a `html/index.html` is generated.

Comment: Thanks, hpk42. That did work. The output .html is basically a printout of the script, but. It's a step forward.

Comment: looks like you need to easy_install the pytest-cov project separately.

Answer (score 15):

if you do not specify --cov=/path/to/code then it will not generate the html at all.

```
$ py.test --cov-report html test_smoke.py
== test session starts == 
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.4.0, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 rootdir: /home/someuser/somedir, inifile: plugins: xdist-1.22.0, forked-0.2, cov-2.5.1 collected 3 items                                                                 


test_smoke.py ...                                             [100%]

== 3 passed in 0.67 seconds ==
```

We can see that there is no message that output was created... However if we specify --cov=...

```
$ py.test --cov-report html test_smoke.py --cov=/path/to/code
== test session starts ==
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.4.0, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/someuser/somedir, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.22.0, forked-0.2, cov-2.5.1
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

test_smoke.py ...                                            [100%] 

---------- coverage: platform linux2, python 2.7.12-final-0 ----------
Coverage HTML written to dir htmlcov
```

We now see that there are no stats for tests that passed, instead we see that coverage was written to HTML and sent to the default directory: ./htmlcov

NOTE: if you want a different directory, then affix :/path/to/directory to the output style html -> py.test --cov-report html:/path/to/htmldir test_smoke.py --cov=/path/to/code

If you see a plain html file, this is an indication that your problem is the --cov=/path/to/my/pkg perhaps... **are you sure that the code you are testing lives here?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate report in html, give full file path of the test file.

```
py.test --cov-report html test_file_name.py --cov=/home/ubuntu/venv/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/test/
```

Then start a python server

```
python -m http.server
```

Navigate to the `html` file in htmlcov directory

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/venv/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/htmlcov/
```

You will see the report