# What is the current way to export HTML reports from pytest?

Tags: pytest

The following post **[Py.Test : Reporting and HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557813/py-test-reporting-and-html-output)** outlines a way to submit py-test with html reports, but it doesnt work with pytest 2.6.1

The "--cov" and "--cov-report" options both fail for me.

Is there a way to generate HTML reports from pytest 2.6.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been useful to show or describe how it fails.  However note that coverage and thus these options are provided by the `pytest-cov` plugin which needs to be installed separately: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cov

If that wasn't the problem then please update the question with more details.

Answer (score 4):

pytest-html is a plugin for py.test that generates a HTML report for the test results. More info @ https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html

Answer (score 0):

This question is ok, but it make the google search result go here:

Below should work normally with Python from 2.7

```
pytest --cov-report=html ...
```

Refer more on: https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reporting.html